# Coffeescript: Multiple Select2 fields on the same page

Tags: coffeescript, select2-rails

I am trying to get multiple Select2 tag fields working on the same page using coffee script and failing :(

I started with this;

```
$(document).on "ready page:load",(
  ->  $("#text_field_1").select2
        tags: ["A", "B", "C"]
  ->  $("#text_field_2").select2
        tags: ["1", "2", "3"]
)
```

No Joy :(
I have it working like this now;

```
text_field_1 = ->
  $("#text_field_1").select2
    tags: ["A", "B", "C"]
text_field_2 = ->
  $("#text_field_2").select2
    tags: ["1", "2", "3"]

$(document).ready(text_field_1)
$(document).on('page:load', text_field_1)
$(document).ready(text_field_2)
$(document).on('page:load', text_field_2)
```

But that doesn't feel like a very good solution.  Can anyone offer any alternatives or tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using `->` correctly. You're just wrapping each line in an anonymous function that you never call, and then passing two

You only need one, passed directly to `$(document).ready`:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#text_field_1").select2
    tags: ["A", "B", "C"]
  $("#text_field_2").select2
    tags: ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Comment: But the `page:load` stuff might be needed depending on how Turbolinks is set up.

Comment: Thanks meagar, I needed the page:load stuff also so I went with the following;
`text_field_1 = ->
  $("#text_field_1").select2
    tags: ["A", "B", "C"]
text_field_2 = ->
  $("#text_field_2").select2
    tags: ["1", "2", "3"]

$(document).ready ->
  text_field_1
  text_field_2
$(document).on 'page:load', ->
  text_field_1
  text_field_2`

Thanks again, Neil

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the suggestion from meager.  The comment I posted did not format very well so here it is again;

```
text_field_1 = ->
  $("#text_field_1").select2
    tags: ["A", "B", "C"]
text_field_2 = ->
  $("#text_field_2").select2
    tags: ["1", "2", "3"]

$(document).ready ->
  text_field_1()
  text_field_2()
$(document).on 'page:load', ->
  text_field_1()
  text_field_2()
```

Thanks